# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS error in JDK 11 to JDK17 migration

Tags: java, xml, dom, runtime-error, java-17

I'm facing this issue in a individual module of a spring boot application while migrating from JAVA 11 to JAVA 17. The parent pom has xercesImpl 2.12.0.SP03 , jaxb-api 2.3.1, jaxb-impl 2.3.2, jersey-media-jaxb 2.31.

There is no error at the compile time build is success, but there is error at the run time.

I have upgrade the spring boot version from 2.3.5 to 2.7.13 and spring-core version from 5.2.20 to 5.3.28

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [SpringConfiguration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ls.DocumentLS
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

I have checked in maven dependencies resolver, that either xercesImpl is coming from some other dependencies in the pom, but it is not. Even I have tried to run by adding it externally in the pom as we are parsing some xml document. But still getting the same issue .

Please advice. Thanks in advance...

```
this is the pom.xml of the concerned module

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco.tibjms</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId></groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId></groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipse-jdt-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
    
        
        <!-- Logback appender using ELK over Kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.danielwegener</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-kafka-appender</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logback appender using ELK over Kafka end -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    


There is JAVA_OPTIONS in start.sh of the project -Dmovement.springInitFiles=SpringConfiguration.xml.
```

And SpringConfiguration.xml is present in the resources folder of the module.

I tried adding externally xerces and xercesImpl in the module by looking some of the solutions Available.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0.SP03</version>
            </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

But it didn't worked. I dont have lesser version of xerces than 2.6.2 in internal repo.